# How do i create this file ??? On ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: 16.04, server, files, kodi

How do i create this file ? In Ubuntu server 16.04 
~/.kodi/userdata/advancedsettings.xml

When I type sudo nano ~/.kodi/userdata/advancedsettings.xml my terminal opens up nano once i type in my desired input and try to save it gives me the following error. [ Error Writing /home/user/.kodi/userdata/advancedsettings.xml:No such file or Directory ]

What am I doing wrong ??? I have also tried cat and touch to see if that would work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong Please Help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the directories first.

Assuming you have installed `kodi`, you may have a directory `.kodi` in your home directory. Do a `cd` to that directory, then see if there is already a directory called `userdata`. I think there is no such directory, which causes the write operation in `nano` to fail. Create that directory with `mkdir userdata`. (There is no need to use `sudo`, indeed it is bad practice, to write files in your own home directory using `sudo`.) Then cd into the `userdata` directory and do `nano advancedsettings.xml`.

That should  help.